# Function returning true/false vs. void when succeeding and throwing an exception when failing

Tags: java, api-design, exceptions, functions, architectural-patterns

I'm building an API, a function that uploads a file. This function will return nothing/void if the file was uploaded correctly and throws an exception when there was some problem.

Why an exception and not just false? Because inside an exception I can specify the reason of failure (no connection, missing filename, wrong password, missing file description, etc.). I wanted to build a custom exception (with some enum to help the API user to handle all the errors).

Is this a good practice or is it better returning an object (with a boolean inside, an optional error message and the enum for errors)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return magic value, throw exception or return false on failure?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159096/return-magic-value-throw-exception-or-return-false-on-failure)

Comment: True and false go well together.  Void and exception go well together.  True and exception go together like cats and taxes.  Someday I may be reading your code.  Please don't do this to me.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Good point, it's meaningless to use true and exception, void and exception would be fine.

Comment: Is this in a Java library binary? A REST endpoint? A SOAP endpoint?

Comment: A java library, a jar.

Comment: I quite like patterns where an object is returned that encapsulates either success or failure. For example, Rust has `Result<T, E>` where `T` is the result if successful and `E` is the error if unsuccessful. Throwing an exception (can be - not so sure in Java) can be expensive as it involves unwinding the call stack, but creating an Exception object is cheap. Obviously, stick to the established patterns of the language you're using, but don't combine booleans and exceptions like this.

Comment: An exception, in general (and by my own convention) represent *exceptional* things that happen, not normal thing. Uploading a file via a network that the user has no control over can fail in a way that's totally expected, and not exceptional in any way.

Comment: Be careful here. You may be headed down a rabbit hole. When your program is capable of dealing with a problem, it's usually easier to just detect and deal with it by checking the preconditions. You would rarely catch an exception, examine its data in code, and try again after fixing the problem. As such, it's rarely valuable to have very many exception types. If you're trying to *log* problems, this makes a lot more sense, but don't expect to write a bunch of catch blocks with significant amounts of code in them.

Comment: If I expected an upload to fail, then I wouldn't bother trying to upload in the first place. Usually, I expect the file to be uploaded. That's the normal case.

Comment: I'd do one OR the other but not both.  If the function uses return values to signal sucess, then logically the samre return value would also indicate failure (true or false).  If the function throws an exception on failure, then checking the return value to check for success is pointless... the mere fact the function returned "normaly" means success in and of itself.  So to answer your question, either true/false and no exception OR void and exceptions all other factors being equivalent.  As to which is better that is an entirely different question (to which Killian provides to)

Comment: @DanPantry In Java, the call stack is checked when *creating* the exception, not when throwing it. `fillInStackTrace();` is called in the super constructor, in the class `Throwable`

Comment: @SimonForsberg oh damn. never mind, then

Comment: You should return false if the error is a normal thing, throw an exception if it means something went wrong. The difference? Normal things are things you check for; things that went wrong are things you don't want to check for (you just want the whole program to display an error)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Throwing an exception is simply an additional way of making a method return a value. The caller can check for a return value just as easily as catch an exception and check that. Therefore, deciding between `throw` and `return` requires other criteria.

Throwing exceptions should often be avoided if it endangers the efficiency of your program (constructing an exception object and unwinding the call stack is much more work for the computer than just pushing a value onto it). But if the purpose of your method is to upload a file, then the bottleneck is always going to be the network and file system I/O, so it's pointless to optimize the return method.

It's also a bad idea to throw exceptions for what should be a simple control flow (e.g. when a search succeeds by finding its value), because that violates the expectations of API users. But a method failing to fulfill its purpose *is* an exceptional case (or at least it should be), so I see no reason for not throwing an exception. And if you do that, you might just as well make it a custom, more informative exception (but it's a good idea to make it a subclass of a standard, more general exception like `IOException`).

Comment: If it is an expected outcome for a file upload request to fail, I would be surprised by an exception thrown in my face (especially if there is a return value in the method signature).

Comment: Note that the reason for making it extend a standard exception is that many (probably even most) callers won't write code to try to *fix* the problem. As a result, most callers will want a simple, "catch this big group of exceptions," without having to list them all explicitly.

Comment: Once you have exceptions for program flow, you end up using them for other functions too - so a file upload that throws might be OK, but then to keep consistency, you'd have functions that check for file existence throw too, and next thing you know, your program is running slowly. Or, you have some functions that return one thing, and others that throw exceptions and then you have a maintenance headache that people will curse you for years to come. Just return a value and save exceptions for exceptional situations.

Comment: @gbjbaanb That's why exceptions should be used when there really is some unfixable situation. When you are trying to open a file and the file can't be read, this is a good case for an exception. When you check for file existence, a boolean needs to be used because it is well expected that the file may not be there.

Comment: Kilian is saying, in the recursive slogan "exceptions are for exceptional situations", exceptional situations are when the function cannot fulfil its purpose. If the function is supposed to read a file, and the file cannot be read *that is exceptional*. If the function is supposed to tell you whether or not a file exists (never mind the potential TOCTOU), then the file not existing *is not exceptional* because the function can still do what it's supposed to do. If the function is supposed to assert that a file exists, then it not existing *is exceptional* because that's what "assert" means.

Comment: Note that the only difference between a function that tells you whether a file exists, and a function that asserts that a file exists, is whether or not the case of the file not existing is exceptional. People sometimes speak as if it's a property of the error condition whether or not it "is exceptional". It is not a property of the error condition, it's a combined property of the error condition and the purpose of the function it occurs in. Otherwise we'd never catch exceptions.

Comment: @hoffmale It's not an expected outcome though; the expectation is that the method does what it is supposed to, which is upload the file.  It didn't though, hence an exception.

Comment: @hoffmale A good rule that I use is 'throw an exception when external circumstances caused the failure'. Incorrect parameters and network timeouts are the obvious scenarios.

Comment: Exceptions don't return a value, they break the normal flow of your program, into an exception body you're supposed to do whatever possible to not make the program crash abruptly. How am I supposed to get a return value from an exception?

Comment: "The caller can check for a return value just as easily as catch an exception" - Actually, that should read **much more easily**.  Exceptions, especially _checked_ exceptions, should be avoided whenever possible.  Doubly so if the method in question can normally be expected to return a result.  It's much easier to inspect that result than it is to have two paths in your code, one for when the method returns normally and one for when it "returns" an `Exception`.  Exceptions subvert normal control-flow, and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: See also: [Which part of throwing an Exception is expensive?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36343209/1267663)

Answer (score 40):

There is absolutely no reason for returning `true` on success if you don't return `false` on failure. What should the client code look like?

```
if (result = tryMyAPICall()) {
    // business logic
}
else {
    // this will *never* happen anyways
}
```

In this case, the *caller* needs a try-catch block anyways, but then they can better write:

```
try {
    result = tryMyAPICall();
    // business logic
    // will only reach this line when no exception
    // no reason to use an if-condition
} catch (SomeException se) { }
```

So the `true` return value is completely irelevant for the caller. So just keep the method `void`.

---

In general, there are three ways to design failure modes.

1. Return true/false
2. Use `void`, throw (checked) exception
3. Return a intermediate *result* object (or a general purpose ADT for this use-case, like `Result<S, E> = Success<S> | Fail<E>`, if your language supports this. Java e.g. will be able to do this once we get sealed types & records).

**Return `true`/`false`**

This is used in some older, mostly c-style APIs. The downsides are obvious, you have no idea what went wrong. PHP does this quite often, leading to code like this:

```
if (xyz_parse($data) === FALSE)
   $error = xyz_last_error();
```

In multi-threaded contexts, this is even worse.

**Throw (checked) exceptions**

This is a nice way to do it. At some points, you can expect failure. Java does this with sockets. The basic assumption is that a call should succeed, but everyone knows that certain operations might fail. Socket connections are among them. So the caller gets forced to handle the failure. its a nice design, because it makes sure the caller actually handles the failure, and gives the caller an elegant way to deal with the failure.

**Return result object**

This is another nice way to handle this. Its often used for parsing or simply things that need to get validated.

```
ValidationResult result = parser.validate(data);
if (result.isValid())
    // business logic
else
    error = result.getvalidationError();
```

Nice, clean logic for the caller as well.

*Using an ADT*

With an ADT, the above code would look like this (yes, even in java, once sealed types & full type patters for switch are implemented):

```
var result = parser.parse(data);
switch (result) {
    case Success (MyDocument document) -> process(document);
    case Fail (ValidationError error) -> showError(error);
}
```

Which also has a nice logic and a nice control flow to it.

---

There is a bit of debate when to use the second case, and when to use the third. Some people believe that exceptions should be *exceptional* and that you should not design with the possibility of exceptions in mind, and will pretty much always use the third options. That is fine. But we have checked exceptions in Java, so I see no reason *not* to use them. I use checked exceptions when the basic assumption is that the call *should* succeed (like using a socket), but failure is possible, and I use the third option when its very unclear whether the call should succeed (like validating data). But there are different opinions on this.

In your case, I would go with `void` + `Exception`. You expect the file upload to succeed, and when it does not, that is exceptional. But the caller is forced to handle that failure mode, and you can return an exception that properly describes what kind of error occurred.

Answer (score 8):

This really comes down to whether a failure is *exceptional* or *expected*.

If an error isn't something you generally expect, then it's reasonably likely the API user will just call your method without any special error handling.  Throwing an exception allows that to bubble up the stack to a place where it gets noticed.

If on the other hand errors are commonplace, you should optimize for the developer who is checking for them, and `try-catch` clauses are a bit more cumbersome than an `if/elif` or `switch` series.

Always design an API in the mindset of someone who is using it.

Comment: In my case, like somebody pointed out, should be an exceptional failure that the API user can't upload the file.

Answer (score 5):

Don't return a boolean if you never intend to return `false`. Just make the method `void` and document that it will throw an exception (`IOException` is suitable) on failure.

The reason for this is that if you do return a boolean, the user of your API may conclude that he/she can do this:

```
if (fileUpload(file) == false) {
    // Handle failure.
}
```

That will not work of course; that is, there is an incongruity between your method's contract and its behaviour. If you throw a checked exception, the user of the method has to handle failure:

```
try {
    fileUpload(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle failure.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your method has a return value, throwing an exception might surprise its users. If I see a method return a boolean, I am pretty convinced it will return true if it succeeds and false if it doesn't, and I will structure my code using an if-else clause. If your exception is going to be based on an enum anyway, you may as well return an enum value instead, similar to windows HResults, and keep an enum value for when the method succeeds.

It is also annoying to have a method throw exception when it is not the final step in a procedure. Having to write a try-catch and divert control flow to the catch block is a good recipe for spaghetti, and should be avoided.

If you are going forward with exceptions, try returning void instead, users will figure out it succeed if no exceptions are thrown, and none will try to use an if-else clause to divert control flow.

Comment: The enum was just an idea to help the API user to handle different types of errors without parsing the error message. So from your point of view in my case is better returning the enum and add an enum for "OK".